# Segmentation fault when using recursive method taking vector as input

Tags: c++, class, recursion, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a very simple filter using recursion but for some reason, I keep getting these Seg Fault.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

class FilterGeneric {
public:
    std::vector<int> filter(std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int>::iterator i); //set i=v.begin() in main
private:
    virtual bool g(int x) =0;
    std::vector<int> result;
};

std::vector<int> FilterGeneric::filter(std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int>::iterator i)   {
    if (i==v.end()) {
        return result;
    }   else    {
        if (g(*i)==true)    {
            result.push_back(*i);
            i++;
            return filter(v,i);
        }   else    {
            i++;
            return filter(v,i);
        }
    }
}

class FilterOdd : public FilterGeneric  {
private:
    bool g(int x);
};

bool FilterOdd::g(int x)    {
    if ((x%2)!=0)   {
        return true;
    }   else    {
        return false;
    }
}

class FilterNonPositive : public FilterGeneric  {
private:
    bool g(int x);
};

bool FilterNonPositive::g(int x)    {
    if (x<0)   {
        return true;
    }   else    {
        return false;
    }
}

class FilterForTwoDigitPositive : public FilterGeneric  {
private:
    bool g(int x);
};

bool FilterForTwoDigitPositive::g(int x)    {
    if (x>=10)   {
        return true;
    }   else    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()  {

    std::vector<int> v;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it=v.begin();

    for (int i=0;i<20;i++)  {
        v.push_back(pow(-1,i)*i);
    }

    std::cout<<std::endl;

    FilterNonPositive fnp;
    FilterForTwoDigitPositive ftd;

    FilterGeneric *f1=&fnp;
    FilterGeneric *f2=&ftd;

    std::vector<int> r1;
    std::vector<int> r2;

    r1=f1->filter(v,it);
    for (it=r1.begin();it!=r1.end();it++)   {
        std::cout<<*it<<" ";
    }
    r2=f2->filter(v,it);
    for (it=r2.begin();it!=r2.end();it++)   {
        std::cout<<*it<<" ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Running out of stack space?

Comment: @user0042 I'm so sorry for my lack of knowledge but is that possible to run out of stack space so easily? I mean, it's such a simple code? I mean, I played games on this computer.

Comment: Stack space is very limited and it's easy to run out of it when using recursive function calls. Rather use a `std::stack` and a simple loop instead.

Comment: @ViệtEnglandI see no conceivable way stack space has *anything* to do with your problem. The answer posted by Employed Russian, however, is *definitely* related, and I strongly suggest you read it and follow the links within.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is here:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<int>::iterator it=v.begin();

for (int i=0;i<20;i++)  {
    v.push_back(pow(-1,i)*i);  // invalidates all iterators into "v"
}
...
r1=f1->filter(v,it);  // using invalidated "it"
```

The problem is that `v.push_back()` *invalidates* all iterators into the vector if the vector needs to be resized. From [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

After you correct above bug by moving `it` initialization after `v` has been intialized, there are additional bugs as well.

If you are building with `g++`, you can use `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to help you find such bugs.

Comment: Interesting, the `pow` function returns a floating point value.  The example provided may have accuracy issues because of conversion to floating point (for parameters) conversion back to integer for the result.